# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home/xeontech/public_html/hrms/application/controllers/admin/Profile.php on line 191

Tags: php, codeigniter

Kindly help me, i am fresher in codeigniter.

```
if( $this->form_validation->run('add_profile_rules') && !empty($this->upload->do_upload('profile_image')) ) { // this is error line of My code
```

and error is on live server but on local server it is working and on another live server it is working

```
public function update_profile($employee_id) {

        $config = [
            'upload_path' => './uploads/profiles/',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg'
        ];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');

        if( $this->form_validation->run('add_profile_rules') && !empty($this->upload->do_upload('profile_image')) ) { // this is error line of My code

            $post = $this->input->post();
            unset($post['submit']);

            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $image_path = "uploads/profiles/" . $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext'];

            $post['profile_image'] = $image_path;

            $this->load->model('Profile_model', 'profile');

            if( $this->profile->update_profile($employee_id, $post) ) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', "Profile Updated Successfully.");
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class', 'alert-success');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', "Profile Failed to Update, Please Try Again");
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class', 'alert-danger');
            }
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');

        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin/edit_profile');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: change condition to `if( $this->form_validation->run('add_profile_rules') && $this->upload->do_upload('profile_image') ) { // this is error line of My code`

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.4.45

Comment: thank u so much now its working